# Yii2 Role swiching after login

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-rbac

A user has 3 roles.

1. RoleOne
2. RoleTwo
3. RoleThree

After Login I want to activate one of his roles active mode and rest of roles inactive mode. Does Yii2 have any role switching technique?
Or we have to make our own logic.

Here is how I am trying to achieve this...

```
$auth = new DbManager;
$auth->init();

//here I will get all roles of user              
$roles = $auth->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
```

Now after this how can set active role from `$roles` variable. In between user can activate other roles also. I am here confused actually there is no yii2 functionality like switching roles any time after login.

Comment: using RBAC you can assign multiple roles to the user so that he can perform  the actions allowed under those roles, but there isnt anything like deactivating temporarily one of the roles for a user, you would have to delete the `auth_assignment` for the user against that specific roles if you do not want the user to perform any task specific to any role, but it means that the role will be dropped and you have to add it again, you might have come up with your own solution, by extending the component classes which are responsible for this task, as much as i know.

Comment: Ohk. @MuhammadOmerAslam if assign a new role to logged in user, How this will react. the page according to the role will change in runtime ??

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 does not provide that extensive function that you're looking for. But
try this https://github.com/webvimark/user-management module though. It is flexible and it has a helper that assigns roles as thus:

```
User::assignRole(Yii::$app->user->identity->id, $roleName)
```

Read the documentation in the link above for more clarification on how it works